# Logarithms using digit recurrence, how many bits to store in a LUT?

Tags: algorithms, arithmetic, floating-point

In a known method for approximating logarithms the following decomposition is adopted (assuming $x \in [1,2)$):

$$
log_2(x) = 1 + \sum_{j=1}^{+\infty} w_i log_2(1+2^{-j})
$$

Where all the coefficients $log_2(1+2^{-j})$ are stored in a LUT table, however for practical reason one can store only values $\psi_j \approx log_2(1+2^{-j})$, [this book](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Bl7xBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=elementary%20functions%20algorithms%20and%20implementation&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj_w7bQ1fjOAhWCPBoKHQYaDUAQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=elementary%20functions%20algorithms%20and%20implementation&f=false) shows an error bound when the $log_2(1+2^{-j})$ are exactly stored, the error is expressed as absolute error (you can look at the section 5.2 of the book). However it doesn't say anything about how many digits should be stored in the LUT in order to have a required accuracy (you can assume absolute error).

I could try some kind of exhaustive search, but I'm quite sure that has to be some "smarter way" to do that, and perhaps I'm not aware of that...

Is there any further reference you could point me out? If not, how could I approach the problem?

Maybe it is not useful but this method I believe is a particular case of the CORDIC iterations, so if there's a way to derive a bound there probably there's the same thing here.

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you tried summing the amount of errors contributed by each term in the sum, to see what the total error could be (at most)?

Comment: For small input sizes I've tried exhaustive search, like increasing one bit per time in the LUT until I reach the required accuracy.

Comment: So the answer is no, you haven't tried upper-bounding the maximum error that could be caused by each term in the sum, and then summing it (using the triangle inequality)?  In that case, I suggest you give that approach a try and see if you can derive a formula for the maximum error, in terms of the accuracy of the LUT entries and show us in the question the best bound you were able to come up with.

Comment: My observation is probably going to be silly... but how can you be sure that the worst case error occurs when you need to sum up all the terms?

Comment: Normally, each tabulated value requires as many bits as there are fractional bits required in the final answer. See, for example, the implementation I provided in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32163873/780717) (the code following the comment `try factors (1+2**(-i))`)

Comment: Sorry but isn't there error? Let's assume each entry has an error of $2^{-n-1}$ and that you need $n$ iterations following the method I mentioned. In such case the error of the answer is bounded by $n2^{n-1}$, am I right? I can understand that "usually" is done in that way, but I was asking is the minimum number of bits to be stored per entry in  such a way that the final answer is affected by an error less than, say, $\epsilon$.

Comment: @user8469759 Re " I was asking is the minimum number of bits to be stored per entry in such a way that the final answer is affected by an error less than, say, ϵ. ". You might want to update your question accordingly, because currently it doesn't say that.